# Multiple Bootable Images on Flash Drive UEFI mode

Tags: grub, mbr, bootable-media, uefi

I am aware that there exists tools that can change the mbr of the drive so that it can boot up  multiple operating systems such as the Windows XP installer, Windows 7 installer, Windows PE-based live environment, and a linux live environment with software like this: http://www.msfn.org/board/topic/120444-how-to-install-windows-from-usb-winsetupfromusb-with-gui/

But all these things are made possible via grub4dos or some variant of that. How would I access the uefi boot options from the Windows 7 installer, for installing in UEFI mode? Some linux distributions such as Ubuntu now also support UEFI mode as well. How would I have a menu, like the grub option, for accessing individual UEFI modes of the images?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pretty much the same way – install an EFI boot manager (such as Gummiboot or grub2-efi) that is capable of "chainloading" other EFI boot loaders, and add the various Windows versions to its menu.

You won't even need to modify bootsectors, since in EFI all boot loaders are just files named `something.efi`. (The one used by Windows is `Bootmfgw.efi`, if I remember correctly.)

Comment: Is it possible to use an EFI boot manager in addition to regular old-fashioned bios boot managers? Not all the systems I'm servicing support EFI.

Comment: It should be. Install the BIOS bootloader the normal way into the bootsector.